# Unable to read the special symbol in oracle

Tags: oracle

I wrote this pl sql block to read from the file which contains special symbol § and executed it in SQL Developer.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
f_dir VARCHAR2(100);
fname VARCHAR2(500);
f utl_file.file_type;
f_line VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
f_dir := 'CCS_RCMS_CHEQUE_LISTENER';
fname := 'SAMPLE.TXT';
f := utl_file.fopen(f_dir,fname,'r');
utl_file.get_line(f,f_line);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1TEST'||f_line);
utl_file.fclose(f);
end;
/
```

It shows the output as below:

```
1TEST0?EBBS?BH?20200520?20200520.ACCOUNT?20200520161733?ACCOUNT?
```

It is not able to display the section symbol.
I ran the sample statement.

```
select replace('My text with [COPY] in it','[COPY]',(UNISTR(CHR(167)))) from dual;
```

Output :
My text with �n it

What needs to be done to read the symbol?

Comment: Show us please your NLS_LANG env variable value? Looks like you are using single byte codepage.

Comment: Can you try `CONVERT()` function which is used to convert a string from a character set to another?

Comment: Hi, Sayan Malakshinov......SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL;  o/p: AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8

Comment: But it looks like your file is in single byte code page. Try to change your nls_lang to the same as your file.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file: SAMPLE.TXT?

Comment: It was ENCODE in ANSI when i checked in Notepad++. I changed the encoding of SAMPLE.TXT to UTF-8 (without BOM) and then used Unix Sed command to replace the special symbol in file with |. It worked as UTL_File read the | character correctly. However the Interface team which sends this file to us is sending without the same encoding so it is again failing to read the special symbol..Any help will be highly appreciated.